# Compactly disable arc-retain-cycles warning for self-referencing blocks

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, clang, automatic-ref-counting

I'm writing an API that involves event handling, and I'd like to be able to use blocks for the handlers. The callbacks will often want to access or modify self. In ARC mode, Clang warns that blocks referencing self are likely to create a retain cycle, which seems like a helpful warning that I want to keep on in general.

However, for this portion of my API, the lifecycle of the callback and the containing object are maintained externally. I know I can break the cycle when the object should be deallocated.

I can turn off the retain cycle warning on a per file basis with `#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-retain-cycles"`, but that disables the warning for the entire file. I can surround the blocks with a `#pragma clang diagnostic push` and `pop` around that warning, but that makes the blocks ugly.

I can also get the warning to go away by referencing a __weak variable pointing to self instead of referencing self directly, but that makes the blocks far less pleasant to use.

The best solution I've come up with is this macro that does the diagnostic disabling around the block:

```
#define OBSERVE(OBJ, OBSERVEE, PATH, CODE) \
[(OBJ) observeObject:(OBSERVEE) forKeyPath:(PATH) withBlock:^(id obj, NSDictionary *change) { \
_Pragma("clang diagnostic push") \
_Pragma("clang diagnostic ignored \"-Warc-retain-cycles\"") \
do { CODE; } while(0); \
_Pragma("clang diagnostic pop") \
}];
```

That works, but it's not very discoverable for API users, it doesn't allow nested observers, and it interacts poorly with XCode's editor. Is there a better way to disable or avoid the warning?

Comment: Creating a `__weak` reference to `self` literally takes one line of code. I think fixing the problem in this case is better than trying to alleviate the symptoms. How does referencing `weakSelf` instead of `self` making the block less pleasant to use?

Comment: It's less pleasant in a couple ways. The listeners are often quite short, sometimes a single statement. The __weak declaration doubles the size of the listener. It also means that you need to qualify property accesses rather than using an inferred self. I will agree that my current solution is probably worse than just using __weak, but I was hoping to get a better one via this question.

Comment: Can you change the prototype of your completion block to accept a "self" argument? Now the code where you pass your blocks will look the same (except for accepting one extra argument) and you can eliminate the warnings. (i.e. have your API pass the object in question to your block)

Comment: also, some code examples might be nice here

Comment: `self` isn't used in enough of the blocks that adding a signature for it would introduce more noise. I've come to accept Mark's position that declaring a `__weak` reference to `self` is less evil than all this wrangling to get away from it. If he wants to add his comment as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: You can disable compiler warnings in targets >> target name >> build settings >> Apple LLVM compiler 3.1 - Warnings

Comment: Instead of replacing `self` with `weakSelf` (and then maybe forgetting to use that one, so still creating a retain cycle), my solution is to `#define self weakSelf` (and `undef` after the block).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To begin with, there is a simple way to disable warnings for certain lines of code using `#pragma`:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "<#A warning to ignore#>"
<#Code that issues a warning#>
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

But I wouldn't use it in this particular case because it won't fix the issue, it'll just hide it from the developer. 
I would rather go with solution that Mark proposed. To create a weak reference, you can do one of the following outside of the block:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self; // iOS ≥ 5
__unsafe_unretained typeof(self) unsafeUnretainedSelf = self; // 5 > iOS ≥ 4
__block typeof(self) blockSelf = self; // ARC disabled
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote the following macro, which *I think*, is pretty clever...

```
#define CLANG_IGNORE_HELPER0(x) #x
#define CLANG_IGNORE_HELPER1(x) CLANG_IGNORE_HELPER0(clang diagnostic ignored x)
#define CLANG_IGNORE_HELPER2(y) CLANG_IGNORE_HELPER1(#y)

#define CLANG_POP _Pragma("clang diagnostic pop")
#define CLANG_IGNORE(x)\
    _Pragma("clang diagnostic push");\
    _Pragma(CLANG_IGNORE_HELPER2(x))
```

It allows you to do all sorts of fun things (without Xcode *haranguing you*), such as..

```
CLANG_IGNORE(-Warc-retain-cycles)
[object performBlock:^(id obj){ [obj referToSelfWithoutWarning:self]; }];
CLANG_POP
```

You can put in any warning flag and Clang will heed to your whims...

```
CLANG_IGNORE(-Warc-performSelector-leaks);
return [self performSelector:someIllBegotSelector withObject:arcFauxPas];
CLANG_POP
```

Then again, the warnings *usually* are there for a reason. Party poppers.

Answer (score 1):

I think disabling the warning is currently the only correct way to do, since it says the compiler: Do not care about this retain cycle, I am aware of it and I will dispose of the observer myself.
Introducing a weak reference is a costly solution since it comes with runtime CPU and memory overhead.

Answer (score 0):

the new LLVM is better at detecting/preventing such retain cycles
wait for LLVM shipping with ios6 or do alex's way with creating a weak var.

disabling the warning is a bad idea though!

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem of the clunkiness of creating a weak reference, I put that into a macro. It uses the preprocessor to create a new var with the same name but with a prefix ('w', in this case; I avoided 'weak' because that would be overkill and mess more with capitalisation rules):

```
#define WEAK_VAR(NAME) __unsafe_unretained typeof(NAME) w##NAME = NAME

...
WEAK_VAR(self);
self.block = ^{
    [wself doStuff];
};
```

If, otoh, a weak reference is not desirable, don't use it! I like nielsbot solution of passing the object as a parameter (when possible, of course).